# C# Microsoft tutorial EF Core with Razor Pages - search parameter

Tags: c#, search

I'm developing a project based on Microsoft's EF Core with Razor Pages Contoso University tutorial, and I'm trying to add an additional search parameter - it would be similar to searching from the student's index page and being able to search by `Course Title` to find all students taking that course.

In the student's `index.cshtml.cs`, `student IQ = studentIQ.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)….`, I cannot get `(s.Course.Title.Contains(searchString)` to work.

What class do I add to so the path to `Course.Title` works?

Comment: Hi Paul, for people to help you it would be good for you to share some code. Do this by adding the code after three backticks (```) here at SO, that way it'll be formatted much better. 

My guess is here you are trying to search on a course name, while the 'course' is null in your view. Entity Framework does something called lazy loading, meaning that any 'child objects' (in this case `course`) is not loaded from the database, and you need to load it explicitly

Answer (score -1):

I checked the [tutorial over at Microsofts website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and they have the following code:

```
IQueryable<Student> studentIQ = from s in _context.Students
                                select s;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    studentIQ = studentIQ.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                           || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
}
```

In this case the code is only loading the student, not any child objects. You need to explicitly include the objects you wish to include, and any related objects within that object (in this case you want student.enrollments.course).

```
IQueryable<Student> studentIQ = _context.Students.Include(st => st.Enrollments).ThenInclude(enr => enr.Course).ToList();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    studentIQ = studentIQ
   .Where(
             s => s.Enrollments
                   .Any(enr => enr.Course.Title.Equals(searchString)
         )
}
```

I would suggest you visit the [Entity Framework "loading related data"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) page in the same docs - this will answer your questions! The good news is that you are doing cool stuff before finishing the tutorial.

Comment: This is not the case of lazy loading so this answer doesn't apply. In the tutorial's code, `studentIQ` is an `IQueryable<T>` so the query hasn't executed. `Include` is not needed for `Where` calls.